# How do I create a check box list when there is no html extension helper method?

Tags: c#, html, code-behind, checkboxlist

I am trying to create a checked box list to so that users can check multiple items in a list (this is being used as a filter option on a search page).

There are html helper methods for list box for, drop down list for, multi select form, etc. How do I go about creating a check box list in C#?

Answer (score 0):

```
var oListBox = new ListBox() { ID = "ID", TabIndex = 10 };
oListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "your text", Value = "your value" });
oListBox.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "your text", Value = "your value" });

.... other items if you want ....

Page.Controls.Add(oListBox);
```